# js-graph.it: How to add Blocks dynamically and build the connections using the Connectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, draw, diagram, graphiti-js

I am using the `js-graph.it` based on the documentation provided [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/js-graph-it/discussion/582282/) and the `JS/CSS` sample provided [here](https://github.com/kostasx/js-graph-it). I am using `jQuery` to create the `Blocks` and `Connectors` dynamically. But for some reason, I am unable to create the `Blocks` and `Connectors`. Can someone please help me with how to achieve this?

I added my code sample in `jsFiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/B_AV_B/L6daqn7e/1/).

I am hoping to create something like this:
[image: CPT2111081318-1890x906]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer as it can be helpful to someone in the future:

I tried a lot of libraries such as `Konva`, `jsPlumb Community Edition`, `Flowchart-vue`, `Vue-konva`, `BPMN` but for some reason, none worked the way I wanted it for my application.

Finally, I found an awesome [Drawflow](https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow) library that can be used to draw `Nodes` and `Connections`. Its author is very active in the Github so I used that and everything is working fine.